# SVM working well on test subset fails on whole dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I trained a SVM iterativly on large chunks of data using sklearn. Each csv file is a part of an image. I made those with a sliding window aproach. I used partial_fit() for fitting the SVM as well as the scaler. The features are the RGBN values of an image, I want to classify the image in two different groups 0 and 1.

```
def trainSVMIterative(directory):

    clf= SGDClassifier(learning_rate = 'constant', eta0 = 0.1, shuffle = False,n_iter_no_change = 5,  warm_start = True )
    sc = StandardScaler()
    firstIter = True
    iter = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
         if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            pixels = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, filename),sep = ',')
            
            #drop columns containing irelevant information
            pixels = pixels.drop('x', axis = 1)
            pixels = pixels.drop('y', axis = 1)


            #dataset
            X = pixels.drop('label', axis = 1)
            #labels
            Y = pixels['label']

            #prepare training data
            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42) 

            #fit scaler
            sc = sc.partial_fit(X)

            #scale input
            X_train = sc.transform(X_train)
            X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

            
            #train svm
            if firstIter:
                 clf.partial_fit(X_train,y_train, classes=np.unique(Y))
                 firstIter = False
            else:
                clf.partial_fit(X_train,y_train)
                testPred = clf.predict(X_test)

                print(classification_report(y_test,testPred))

                iter+=1
                print(iter) 

            

    return clf, sc
```

When i print the classification report after each iteration it looks fine, the accuracy goes up to 98%. I therefore assume my classifier is training properly.
For testing, I extracted a new dataframe from my original image. This time, there is no column with the label. I pass the classifier as well as the scaler to my testing function

```
def testClassifier(path, classifier, scaler):
     #opening the original image, same process as in creating the training data
     raster = gdal.Open(path)
     array = tifToImgArray(raster, 'uint8')
     
     # select a part of the image to test on
     windowSize = 1000
     y = 19000
     x = 0
     window = array[y:y + windowSize,x:x + windowSize]

     #create the dataframe
     arrayData = []
 
     for i in range(window.shape[0]):
        for j in range(window.shape[1]):
           
            arrayData.append([i,j,array[i,j,0],array[i,j,1],array[i,j,2],array[i,j,3]])
                          
     dfData = pd.DataFrame(arrayData, columns=['x','y','R','G','B','N'])

     #again drop psoition information
     pixels = dfData.drop('x', axis = 1)
     pixels = pixels.drop('y', axis = 1)

     

     #use scaler 
     pixels = scaler.transform(pixels)
     
     #make prediction
     prediction = classifier.predict(pixels)
     

     image = visualizePrediction(prediction, window, dfData)     
            
            
     return image
```

My problem now is, the classifier predicts label "1" for every pixel. Dataframe X I used for testing is the same I used in one of training runs, there is just no split in trainig an test data, I just used the whole set. I dont really get what im doing wrong since the classifier worked pretty good on  a subset of X. I was thinking it might be a problem that there a more Datapoints labeled as "1" then there are labeled as "0" and I dont use any weight on the Data. But then again why does it work when i split the dataset into X_train and X_test since this is also the case there.
I would apreciate help on this issue.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the accuracy of our model is very high, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's doing very well all the time(it might on train_data but not on test_data).

  Example: Let's say we have some 100 rows of data where `label1 = 90 #rows` and `label0 = 10 #rows`. We do the usual `test_train_split` and train our model(in our case, it's a classification model) and see that the accuracy is 95%. Since our model is soo perfect, we deploy it and a few days later we notice that it's not predicting as good as it did during our training. The reason is because is data is skewed. Even when the model predicts the "label0" wrong, the accuracy still increases as the "label1" prediction dominates the other and I think this is exactly what's happening with your data.
- We can check this using [Confusion Matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) once we did the prediction. Confusion matrix evaluates the performance of our model. We also have other metrics such as [F1 score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html), [Roc curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) which are quite useful as well.
- We can solve this by getting our data into right distribution. But most of the time we are short of data and all the data which we have is this skewed data. In such cases we can do something called [Oversampling and Undersampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis).

Comment: My problem is that my model works fine on test_data, it fails on test_data+ train_data, so the whole dataset. I also checked the F1 Score which is 99% for data with label1 and 50% for label0. It seems odd to me that that the model fails on the data it has been trained on together with the data it predicted mostly correct my first function.

I will try your second point and select only the balanced chucks of data for the training and see what happens.

Comment: Since you said, the overall data has more label1, it is safe to assume that when you did the train_test_split the split test_data had more label1. Now imagine what the accuracy would be when it predicted 90% label1 correctly but failed 10%label0. Yes, the accuracy would be higher but it's useless.
For now, try with somewhat balanced data and let me know how it went. I am quite curious about the accuracy at each step and also the confusion matrix but that's for later. Anyway, remember to always do some quick [EDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis) to avoid such things.

Comment: Balancing the data improved the prediction by a lot, you where right about that.
I had a look on the confusion matrix at every step and it turned out that the predictions for label0 where really bad and quite good for label1. What I wonder tho, is that the modell had at least some correct label0 predictions at every step so why does it predict the very same points wrong when used without making a split? Anyway thank u very much for ur help.